# How to store values from html tags in database in django?

Tags: django

I am new to django,I want to store the data which I enter into my html text tags to be stored in my SQLite database,I know I'm missing out on some code so please suggest me.

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<header style="background-color:blue;">
<h1 >Test template</h1></header>
     <script>
        function myfunc()
        alert("data saved")
     </script>

</head>

<body style="background-color:#FFD700">
<p>
<form>
question: <input type="text" name="question"><br>
answer: <input type="text" name="answer"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myfunc()">save</button>
</form>
</p>
</center>  
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 

def Index(request):
   return render_to_response('Index.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.CharField('max_length=200')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

Comment: Read about [Django Forms](http://serk.io/topics/forms/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get value from html form into database using django python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521991/how-to-get-value-from-html-form-into-database-using-django-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.
In template:

```
<form action="/url" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
question: <input type="text" name="question"><br>
answer: <input type="text" name="answer"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myfunc()">save</button>
</form>
```

In views.py:

```
def Index(request):
   new_poll= Poll() #call model object
   d= request.POST
   new_poll.question= d['question']
   new_poll.question= d['answer']
   new_poll.save()
   return render_to_response('Index.html')
```